# How to solve $(a+bc)(d'+bc)(a'+d')$ using Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

I have done this. is this correct? If wrong, what is needed to be changed?

$(a+bc)(d'+dc)(a'+d')$

$ = ad'a' + abcd' + bcd'a' + bcbcd'$

$ = d' + abcd' + bcd'a' + bcbcd'$

$ = d' + bcd' (a + a' + bc)$

$ = d' + bcd' \cdot (1)$

$ = d'(1+bc)$

$ = d'$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Your question and title are different.